# Why is every local minimum of a neural network with one layer and $H$ hidden units in a family of size $H!2^H$?

Tags: neural-networks

> Every local minimum of a feedforward neural network with one layer and $H$ hidden units is in a family of size $H!2^H$ (MacKay 1992) [(link to paper)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e5c6/a695a4455a526ec8955dcc0fa2d6810089e9.pdf)

I find it very intuitive that there are several equivalent minima. For example, by interchanging the order of each hidden unit, the output is unchanged, so from here we get a factor $H!$. I don't understand where the factor $2^H$ comes from.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but if the activation used is even ($f(x) = -f(-x)$), then one could choose to "flip" a neuron by flipping the sign of all the input and the output weights associated with that neuron. The ability to do this or not to do this for each neuron gives $2^H$ total choices. tanh is a popular activation function with this property, as well as no activation.

Comment: It sounds very convincing to me. I am willing to accept it if you write it is an an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the activation used is an even function: $f(x)=−f(−x)$, then one could choose to "flip" a neuron by flipping the sign of all the input and the output weights associated with that neuron. The ability to do this or not to do this for each neuron gives $2^H$ total choices. Both the `tanh` function and the identity activation (no activation) are often used in neural networks and fit this criteria.